# possible to join a table on only one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a temporary table I'm creating in a sproc that houses my user information.  I need to join this table to another table that has SEVERAL rows for that particular user but I only want to return one result from the "many" table.

something like this

```
SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname
FROM #users AS u
INNER JOIN OtherTable AS ot on u.userid = (top 1 ot.userid)
```

obviously that wont' work but that's the gist of what I'm trying to do for two reasons, one I only want one row returned (by a date field descending) and two for optimaztion purposes.  The query has to scan several thousand rows as it currently is..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
   u.firstname, u.lastname, t.*
FROM
   #users AS u
   CROSS APPLY
   (SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM OtherTable AS ot 
    WHERE u.userid = ot.userid
   ORDER BY something) t
```

Comment: ok this looks to have real promise....I"m getting a syntax error inside my sub-select though on the join portion.  Do I need to specify a join type when joining the other table to users?

Comment: I see you updated to use a "WHERE JOIN" and this works perfectly.  Thanks much!

Comment: @Christopher Johnson: yes, copy/paste error sorry that I spotted after

Answer (score 2):

Use the ROW_NUMBER() function to order your rows by datetime and then filter by row_num = 1

```
;WITH otNewest
AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM othertable  
    WHERE ROW_NUM() OVER(partition by userid order by datetime DESC) = 1
)
SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname, o.*
FROM #users U
INNER JOIN otNewest O
    ON U.userid = O.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if you're joining but not returning any columns from `OtherTable`, then you're only interested in checking for existence?

```
SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname 
    FROM #users AS u 
    WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
                     FROM OtherTable ot
                     WHERE u.userid = ot.userid)
```

Comment: no I'm sorry, I should've been more clear in my moch-up.  I do need to return some information from the other table as well, just from the first row returned (by the date field descending)

Comment: @Christopher: In that case, see [@gbn's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987532/possible-to-join-a-table-on-only-one-row/6987546#6987546).